# SQL : extract next character from string where multiple separators exist

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Azure MSSQL Database

I have a column that contains values stored per transaction. The string can contain up to 7 values, separated by a `'-'`.

I need to be able to extract the value that is stored after the 3rd `'-'`. The issue is that the length of this column (and the characters that come before the 3rd `'-'`) can vary.

For example:

```
DIM VALUE
1. NHL--WA-S-MOSG-SER-
2. VDS----HAST-SER-
3. ---D---SER
```

- Row 1 needs to return `'S'`
- Row 2 needs to return `'-'`
- Row 3 needs to return `'D'`

Comment: `-` character is known as _hyphen_ or _dash_. What should be returned if column value contains less than three hyphens or the third hyphen is the last character?

Comment: It won't have less than 3. This column will always contain 6

Comment: if the dash is the separator wouldn't row 2 just be a blank and not a dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means an optimal solution, but it works in SQL Server.

TempTable added for testing purposes. Maybe it gives you a hint as of where to start.

Edit: added reference for [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function (works from SQL Server 2016 up).

```
CREATE TABLE #tempStrings (
    VAL VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO #tempStrings VALUES ('NHL--WA-S-MOSG-SER-');
INSERT INTO #tempStrings VALUES ('VDS----HAST-SER-');
INSERT INTO #tempStrings VALUES ('---D---SER');
INSERT INTO #tempStrings VALUES ('A-V-D-C--SER');

SELECT 
    t.VAL,
    CASE t.PART WHEN '' THEN '-' ELSE t.PART END AS PART
FROM
    (SELECT
        t.VAL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VAL ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS IX,
        value AS PART
    FROM #tempStrings t
    CROSS APPLY string_split(VAL, '-')) t
WHERE t.IX = 4; --DASH COUNT + 1

DROP TABLE #tempStrings;
```

Output is...

```
VAL                  PART
---D---SER           D
A-V-D-C--SER         C
NHL--WA-S-MOSG-SER-  S
VDS----HAST-SER-     -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the fourth element then using `CHARINDEX` is relatively straightforward:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    rowId   INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    xval    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES 
    ( 'NHL--WA-S-MOSG-SER-' ),
    ( 'VDS----HAST-SER-' ),
    ( '---D---SER' ),
    ( 'A-V-D-C--SER' );


;WITH cte AS
( -- Work out the position of the 3rd dash
SELECT
    rowId, 
    xval,
    CHARINDEX( '-', xval, CHARINDEX( '-', xval, CHARINDEX( '-', xval ) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1 xstart
FROM #tmp t
), cte2 AS
( -- Work out the length for the substring function
SELECT rowId, xval, xstart, CHARINDEX( '-', xval, xstart) - (xstart) AS xlen
FROM cte
)
SELECT rowId, ISNULL( NULLIF( SUBSTRING( xval, xstart, xlen ), '' ), '-' ) xpart
FROM cte2
```

I also did a volume test at 1 million rows and this was by far the fastest method compared with `STRING_SPLIT`, `OPENJSON`, recursive CTE (the worst at high volume).  As a downside this method is less extensible, say you want the second or fifth items for example.